# Нужна критика по архитектуре классов в С++ для реализации таблиц ModBus

Tags: c++, наследование, шаблоны-с++, modbus

Изучаю С++ и пишу библиотеку ModBus. Прошу полезного совета у Гуру по изменению архитектуры в целом или ответить на конкретные вопросы в конце.

Я хочу с помощью шаблонов классов автоматически помещать любые пользовательские данные в нужные таблицы данных ModBus с возвращением указателей на них.

```
class AlarmData_b01
{
    bool isAlarm;
    bool isCountActivate;
};

class MeintenanceData_b01
{
    bool isMeintenance;
    bool isCountActivate;
};

class MeintenanceData_f32
{
    unsigned short Id;
    unsigned long Time;
    float Rate;
};

AlarmData_b01       *AlarmData_b01_Alarm1_ptr       = InputBits<AlarmData_b01>::Add();
AlarmData_b01       *AlarmData_b01_Alarm2_ptr       = InputBits<AlarmData_b01>::Add();

MeintenanceData_b01 *AlarmData_b01_Meintenance1_ptr = InputBits<MeintenanceData_b01>::Add();
MeintenanceData_b01 *AlarmData_b01_Meintenance2_ptr = InputBits<MeintenanceData_b01>::Add();

MeintenanceData_f32 *AlarmData_f32_Meintenance1_ptr = InputRegs<MeintenanceData_f32>::Add();
MeintenanceData_f32 *AlarmData_f32_Meintenance2_ptr = InputRegs<MeintenanceData_f32>::Add();
```

Таким образом, для класса AlarmData  создается свой класс, регистрирующий все объекты типа AlarmData. Тоже происходит и для класса MeintenanceData. Дискретные данные для аварий помещаются в таблицу дискретных данных, а данные 16 бит помещаются в таблицу регистров модбас.

Так же с помощью статического метода шаблонного класса можно задать адрес для созданной области объектов в таблице ModBus.

```
InputBits<AlarmData_b01>::AddresSet(100);
InputBits<MeintenanceData_b01>::AddresSet(110);

InputRegs<MeintenanceData_f32>::AddresSet(100);
```

Таким образом будут формироваться таблицы данных, доступ к которым будет осуществляться из вне сторонним устройством по интерфейсу RS485 и протоколу ModBus с заданием адреса внутри посылки, указанного в моей программе с помощью AddresSet.

В начале мной был создан базовый шаблон класса

```
template <typename T_DataType>
class ModBusTables
{
    protected:

    static unsigned short   Addres;
    static unsigned short AreaSize;
    T_DataType *AreaData_ptr;

    ModBusTables();

    public:

    static void AddresSet(unsigned short ModBusAddres);
};
```

где

```
static unsigned short Addres        - Адрес области в таблице протокола Модбас
static unsigned short AreaSize      - Размер объектов в области
T_DataType            *AreaData_ptr - Тип для приведения указателя.
```

Так как в ModBus фактически существует только два типа данных: дискретные и ячейки по 16 бит, то в параметрах данного шаблона будет либо bool либо unsigned short. Таким образом AreaData_ptr - это указатель на тип данных конкретной таблицы ModBus, чтобы можно было путешествовать по любым данным пользователя с помощью единого указателя.

Теперь приведу код шаблонного класса, который наследуется от одного из классов выше и расскажу в чем заключается вопрос.

```
template <class T_DataStruct, class Specialization> class ModBusTable;

template <class T_DataStruct, typename T_DataType, template<typename> class TT_Table>
class ModBusTable<T_DataStruct, TT_Table<T_DataType> > : public TT_Table<T_DataType>
{
    private:

    T_DataStruct AreaData;

    public:

    static T_DataStruct *Add()
    {
        ModBusTable *ModBusArea_ptr = new ModBusTable();

        T_DataStruct *Instance_Ptr = &ModBusArea_ptr->AreaData;

        ModBusTable<T_DataStruct, TT_Table<T_DataType> >::AreaSize  = sizeof(ModBusArea_ptr->AreaData);
        ModBusArea_ptr->AreaData_ptr = (T_DataType *)Instance_Ptr;

        return Instance_Ptr;
    }
};
```

Главная задача данного шаблонного класса - создать свой объект в статическом методе, зарегистрировать его в классе и возвратить указатель на данные пользовательского типа, а так же преобразовать этот указатель в указатель AreaData_ptr объявленный в родительском классе, чтобы с любыми пользовательскими типами можно было работать через указатель на bool или unsigned short.

Теперь сам вопрос. Для того, чтобы не вбивать много параметров в шаблон для регистрирования пользовательских данных в конкретной таблице ModBus, я применил наследование.

```
template <class T> class InputBits:     public ModBusTable<T, ModBusTables<bool> >  {};
template <class T> class InputRegs:     public ModBusTable<T, ModBusTables<unsigned short> > {};
template <class T> class OutputBits:    public ModBusTable<T, ModBusTables<bool> > {};
template <class T> class OutputRegs:    public ModBusTable<T, ModBusTables<unsigned short> > {};
```

Как логически объединить объекты классов

```
 InputBits<AlarmData_b01> и InputBits<MeintenanceData_b01>?
```

Объекты этих классов логически должны находится в одной таблице ModBus.

Существует ли способ заменить наследование в данном случае на что-то похожее на alias template в С++11, чтобы создавать шаблон класса с новым именем InputBits по шаблону ModBusTable? Так, чтобы работало выражение

```
 InputBits<AlarmData>::Add()
```

Приму любые советы по изменению архитектуры реализации данной задачи. Большое спасибо за прочтение, внимание и ответы!

Comment: Необходимо определить 4 шаблона используя один. InputBits<T> как ModBusTable<T, InputBitsTable<bool> >; InputRegs<T> как ModBusTable<T, InputRegsTable<unsigned short> >; OutputBits<T> как ModBusTable<T, OutputBitsTable<bool> >; и OutputRegs<T> как ModBusTable<T, OutputRegsTable<unsigned short> >. Это как-нибудь можно сделать с помощью typedef?

Comment: @Ilia Если доступны возможности C++11, то можно задействовать [alias template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) пример на http://ideone.com/n8bD5I

Comment: @ Maxim Timakov Спасибо, это именно то, что мне нужно! Но мне доступен только С++03.

Comment: @Ilia тогда можно через структуры, но ИМХО, это будет не очень удобно. Пример http://rextester.com/CYCZ16660

Comment: Хотя, можно применить макросы, но с ними надо быть осторожным. Пример http://rextester.com/NBPUC4137

Comment: @ Maxim Timakov Спасибо за всесторонний ответ. Вы мне очень помогли!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для стандарта C++11 и новее можно было бы записать

```
template<class A, class B>
struct Base{};

template<class A>
using WrapperFirst = Base<A, int>;

template<class A>
using WrapperSecond = Base<A, double>;

int main() {
    WrapperFirst<int> a;
    WrapperSecond<int> b;

    return 0;
}
```

Полного аналога [alias template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) в `C++03` построить не получится.

Можно использовать шаблон структуры для частичного задания параметров базового шаблона.

```
template<class A, class B>
struct Base{};

template<class A>
struct Wrapper
{
    typedef Base<A, int> first;
    typedef Base<A, double> second;
};

int main() {
    Wrapper<int>::first a;
    Wrapper<int>::second b;

    return 0;
}
```